# How does malloc works in this case?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

Here is code of my program I use `gcc -Wall -ansi -g`

This program makes binary tree and prints it in order. But there is problem for me.

I can't make my root  = NULL and have to alloc memory that should in my opinion be marked on NULL.

There is another problem. How does it work if there is no NULL but allocated memory? Does malloc allocate memory of `(*root) -> right_child` or `left_child` on NULL. I totally don't get it. There is Segmentation fault if I don't allocate memory like this. Any help and critic will be welcome.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*struct for node it has pointers and value*/
struct node {
    struct node *left_child ;
    struct node *right_child;
    int val;
};

/*Prints error message out of memory*/

void outOfMemoryError(void){
    fprintf (stderr,"out of memory error :(\n");
    fflush(stderr); 
    exit (123);
}

/*print tree inorder*/
void printTreeInOrder (struct node **rootNode){
    if ( (*rootNode) == NULL)
    {   
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("## my node is null");
#endif

        return;
    } 
    if ( (*rootNode)->left_child !=NULL){
        printTreeInOrder( (*rootNode) ->left_child);
    }

    printf ("%d ",(*rootNode) ->val);
    if ((*rootNode)->right_child !=NULL){
        printTreeInOrder((*rootNode)->right_child);
    }
}

/*add node uses recursion*/
void addNode (struct node **root, int value ){
    if ( (*root) == NULL) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("## my root is null\n");
        fflush (stdout);
#endif
        (*root) = malloc (sizeof (struct node));

        if (root == NULL)
            outOfMemoryError();
        (*root) ->val = value;    
        /* I don't know why I have to malloc this memory instead using NULL*/
        (*root) ->left_child = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
        (*root) ->right_child = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    }
    else if ((*root) ->val > value){
        addNode ((*root)->right_child,value);
    }
    else  
        addNode ((*root)->left_child,value);

}

int main(void)
{   
    /*input vars*/
    char string [80];
    int temp = 0;

    /*root of the whole tree*/
    struct node *root = malloc (sizeof (struct node));

    printf ("i will add to binnary tree as long as int is bigger than 0\n");
    while (1) {
        fgets (string,sizeof(string),stdin);
        sscanf(string,"%d",&temp);
        if (temp <= 0)
            break;
        addNode(root,temp);
    }
    printf("Printing tree Inorder\n");
    printTreeInOrder(root); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(*root) ->left_child = malloc (sizeof (struct node));` should be `(*root) ->left_child = NULL;` (same for right_child)

Comment: From a quick view those double pointers don't seem completely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a memory leak with the first malloc, if I correctly read what your `addNode` function should do.

=> You pass a pointer to a pointer of `struct node` (ie: `struct node* *` [notice the space]). So, addNode should update the `struct node*` to reflect a new root. That why you need to pass an address (eg: `&root`).

I would expect that addNode use that pointer to create (eg: malloc) a new `struct node` and store to that the caller get the new value. eg:

```
struct node* root = NULL;

...

addNode(&root, temp);
```

And in addNode:

```
    (*root) ->left_child = NULL;
    (*root) ->right_child = NULL;
```

Because by design, left_child will be a "root" (the first arg of addNode), and it will create the node.

Then:

```
   else if ((*root) ->val > value){
        addNode (&((*root)->right_child),value);
   } else {
        addNode (&((*root)->left_child ),value);
   }
```

Because it will not update the content of `root->left/right_child` if you don't pass a pointer to a `struct node*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Node* when the expected parameter is Node**. You need to pass as &node. You must reference the pointer before you pass it into the function. Also The allocation wont stick unless you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys you helped me a lot! This code is working, I tested it with random generated test (and valgrind (heap blocks were freed).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*struct for node it has pointer and value*/
struct node {
    struct node *left_child ;
    struct node *right_child;
    int val;
};

/*prints to stderr with flushing buffor 
 *NOTE: add newline on output
 *NOTE: require -DDEBUG in compilator command*/
void debugPrint(char * string){
#ifdef DEBUG    
    fprintf (stderr,"%s\n",string);
    fflush(stdout);
#endif
}


/*Prints error message out of memory*/

void outOfMemoryError(void){

    fprintf (stderr,"out of memory error :(\n");
    fflush(stderr); 
    exit (123);
}

/*print tree inorder*/
void printTreeInOrder (struct node* *root){
    if ( (*root) == NULL)
    {   
        return;
    } 
    if ( (*root)->left_child !=NULL){
        printTreeInOrder( &(*root) ->left_child);
    }

    printf ("%d ",(*root) ->val);
    if ((*root)->right_child !=NULL){
        printTreeInOrder( &(*root)->right_child);
    }
}

/*add Node uses recursion*/
void addNode (struct node* *root, int value ){
    if ( (*root) == NULL) {
        debugPrint("I'm in null of addnote");
        (*root) = malloc (sizeof (struct node));

        if ((*root) == NULL)
            outOfMemoryError();
        (*root) ->val = value;      

        (*root) ->left_child = NULL;
        (*root) ->right_child = NULL;
        debugPrint("I'm out null of addnote");  
    }
    else if ((*root) ->val > value){
        debugPrint("I'm sending Value to right");
        addNode (&(*root)->right_child,value);
    }
    else { 
        addNode (&(*root)->left_child,value);
        debugPrint("I'm sending Value to left");
    }
}


/*uses postOrder to delete all tree node*/
void deleteTree(struct node* *root){
    if ( (*root) == NULL)
    {   
        return;
    } 
        deleteTree( &(*root) ->left_child);
        deleteTree( &(*root)->right_child);
        free ( *root);
}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{   
    /*input vars*/
    char string [80];
    int temp = 0;

    /*root of the whole tree*/
    struct node *root = NULL;

    printf ("i will add to binnary tree as long as int is bigger than 0\n");
    while (1) {
        fgets (string,sizeof(string),stdin);
        sscanf(string,"%d",&temp);
        if (temp <= 0)
            break;
        addNode(&root,temp);
    }
    printf("Printing tree Inorder\n");
    printTreeInOrder(&root); 
    deleteTree(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: at addNode `if (root == NULL) outOfMemoryError();` --> `if (*root == NULL) outOfMemoryError();`